# Obtengo error en tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip

error in tooltip, por que? necesito popers?

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: el error era la direccion node_modules\popper.js\dist que esta mal, lo modifique node_modules\popper.js\dist\umd y funciono!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Es debido a que utilizas una version antigua de la librería popper.

Esta librería es la que debes utilizar:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

> Cuando utilices librerías como por ejemplo **bootstrap**, tienes que
>   revisar cuando actualicen algo, por que como en este caso pueden dejar
>   de dar servicio para "parchear" bugs o añadir mejoras.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!"><b>Hover over me</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Aunque he estado mirando y el ejemplo que muestras también aparece [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp), y sinceramente me gusta más el de esa vieja versión que el de ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Solo añade el siguiente script

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hola, soy un tooltip">Aqui tu mensaje</a>
```

más la librerias de bootstrap y todo funcionara bien. Saludos